# I have an AJaX post call in jquery. I am confused with post and get calls . MVC4 C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

1) I want to send some data to Action-controller and process it, if success I want to redirect to different action and show it's view .

I have done it with Ajax "post" call I decorated my action with [httppost].
but in navigation part I am stuck . 
on success although  my code going to different action's View but it not rendering that view!!

2) I am confused with "post" and "get" thing's in both controller head and ajax call , because in both case we can send data to controller and again jumped to jquery code in same view.

PS: If my ajax call is doing "post" Call hit then what will be in my controller action's head(post or get)?

Comment: stick with the value if its post in ajax then post is in C#

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, then do not use ajax to submit.

Comment: @madalinivascu ok thanks, and how to redirect to different view if i want to..  or how to reload same page with fresh and clear data and a lable message.!

Comment: @ManojKargeti if you want to redirect after ajax then do a simple post/get request and drop the ajax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to another page after ajax post then use window.location.href in ajax success callback.

```
success:function(data,textStatus,xhr){
    window.location.href="@Url.Action("ActionName","Controllername")";
}
```

Comment: can we send some parameter's with this url from controller. also do i have to change the return type of controller

Comment: can we send some parameter's with this url from controller. also do i have to change the return type of controller

Comment: can we send some parameter's with this url from controller. also do i have to change the return type of controller @APECE

Comment: No, u don't need to change the return type of controller.If u want to send parameter use "@Url.Action("Actionname", "Controllername", new {id=0})".If this way helps you mark the above as answer

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page - its nonsense to use ajax if OP wants to redirect

Comment: window.location.href= 'Url.Action("Actionname", "Controllername", new {id=data.id, id2=data.id2})' is it not working neither data resolved for this in url @APECE

Comment: you are passing the data.id variable as a string in url.change that